# Reading values from a standard graph in Excel for an automated calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I am building a spreadsheet calculator for my work and with the standard I am using for the backbone there are 2 graphs that are used in the calculation process. I am struggling to think of a methodology to automate the output value in each case

Graph 1 - the user determines the intersection point of the x and y coord and the area the point is located in is the answer ie low, med or high dilution

Graph 2 - the user is determining the Y value by selection the appropriate line and then using where the x-coord touches the line to find the y-value

One potential method i have thought about for Graph 2 is to determine the equation of each line and then have excel solve for y in each case. I don't think this will be the most elegant solution

Any help is greatly appreciated

[Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL8Ub.png)

[Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9nTr.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Graph 1, it would seem you need a nested IF:

```
= IF( y > 12*x, "high",
      IF( y > 1.2*x - 0.005, "medium",
             "low" ) )
```

where y and x are cell references to those variables.

I don't understand the objective of Graph2 - perhaps an example would help. But why can't you just do JET(x), DIFFUSE(x) and HEAVY_GAS(x) where those represent the functions that created those outputs?

Comment: Thanks Mark,
That makes sense for graph 1 and a lot neater than what I though.

Graph 2 is to get the y-value depending on the type of release/fluid  (ie Jet, Diffuse or Heavy Gas). I think your suggestion is similar to the was I was thinking of doing it and will try that way.

Thanks for your help and hope your having a good day